# how to use page without tabs in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to use new page in ionic, i create new route in app.js , but when i run this page nothing is showing.

thanks for help.

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('etudiant', {
            url: '/etudiant',
            controller: 'etudiantCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'etudiant.html'
    })
      .state('tabs', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })
      .state('tabs.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
          'home-tab' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.list', {
        url: '/list',
        views: {
          'list-tab' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
            controller: 'ListController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'login-tab' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.detail', {
        url: '/list/:aId',
        views: {
          'list-tab' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
            controller: 'ListController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.welcome', {
        url: '/welcome',
        views: {
          'welcome-tab' : {
            templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
            controller: 'ListController'
          }
        }
      })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');
  })
```

**index.html**

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-view>

    </ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home"
           href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Formation" icon="ion-calendar"
           href="#/tab/list">
    <ion-nav-view name="list-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Espace Etudiant" icon="ion-ios-people"
           href="#/tab/login">
    <ion-nav-view name="login-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**etudiant.html**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  <h2 class="title">welcome</h2>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Comment: check for console errors?

Comment: templateUrl: 'etudiant.html' ||| Sure that shouldnt be templates/edudiant.html?

Comment: nothing showing in console.
path of my file etudiant.html : templates/etudiant.html.

Comment: i change the path but probleme stay ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes if you want to add a page before your tabs.

1. In app.js change the following line to find correct path to the file, otherwise it will not load:
   `templateUrl: 'etudiant.html'`  to
   `templateUrl: 'templates/etudiant.html'`
2. In app.js also change the following line to default to this page when running the app `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');`  to  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/etudiant');`
3. Add logic to **etudiant.html** so you can leave this page and get to your tabs

   ```
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
     <h2 class="title">welcome</h2>
   </ion-header-bar>

   <ion-view>
       <ion-content>
           <h1>Testing</h1>
           <button ng-click="leave()">Leave</button>
       </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
   ```
4. Add logic to **etudiantCtrl** to route you to the tabs view

   ```
   .controller('etudiantCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
     $scope.leave = function(){
       console.log('Leaving...')
       $state.go('tab.home');
     }
   })
   ```